# What kind of markup to use on a website to make data more semantic?

Tags: semantic-web

With all the talk about the semantic web these days, are there any pointers of special markup to use for indexing businesses?

For example a website that has an index of restaurants and a map of their location,

- How to make each restaurant name/info more semantic?
- How to make the geo location easier to recognize for robots and accessibility devices?

And what other things can make such a website more usable, semantically, to users and indexing robots?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Microformats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microformat) is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Wow. Does it make coffee? Will google love me?

Comment: It won't make the coffee for you but it will markup it up semantically for you once it's made.

Comment: HTML5 also addresses a lot of these issues.

Answer (score 3):

There is also the Search Engine schema.org ( http://schema.org ), which differ from microformats and generally use html attributes instead of things like classes for rich snippets.

Comment: Schema.org seems to be what Google is suggesting nowadays and compliments HTML5 better in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, and it's really really simple to mark up on a site that already has it's html in place, since you're essentially adding attributes, not subtracting anything.